# ItemsControl + Textbox + MVVM + EventTrigger Not Firing

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm, eventtrigger

Since I moved my View inside an ItemsControl, I cannot get the EventTrigger to fire in my ViewModel. Here is my Commmand Declaration which should fire on LostFocus:

```cs
public ICommand UpdateOrdersCommand { get; set; }
public void UpdateOrders(object param)
{
    UpdateFields();
}
```

My Container XAML:

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
  <WMS:PurchasingModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
  <DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate1">
    <WMSViews:Purchasing1 />
  </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="White"
      DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ColPurchasing}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource     myDataTemplate1}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

My View where this EvenTrigger used to fire on LostFocus:

```
<Classes:TextBoxEx TabIndex="1"
                   x:Name="tbFoodSales"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Height="23"
                   Margin="55,79,0,0"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Width="61"
                   TextAlignment="Right"
                   Text="{Binding Path=FoodSales, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateOrdersCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Classes:TextBoxEx>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bind with element this way:

```
<Classes:TextBoxEx TabIndex="1"
                   x:Name="tbFoodSales"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Height="23"
                   Margin="55,79,0,0"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Width="61"
                   TextAlignment="Right"
                   Text="{Binding Path=FoodSales, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=UserControlName, Path=DataContext.UpdateOrdersCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Classes:TextBoxEx>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'UpdateOrdersCommand' binding will be looking for that Command on the actual item. E.G. If 'ColPurchasing' was a collection of 'Purchase' objects, it would be trying to find Purchase.UpdateOrdersCommand

I'm guessing your UpdateOrdersCommand is actually in your 'ViewModel' class

Depending on how you have things structured, the following may work

```
Command="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.UpdateOrdersCommand}" />
```

This tells the binding to look for the Command on the LayoutRoot's DataContext, which in your case should be your 'ViewModel'. This works in Silverlight and probably WPF, but if you are using WPF I think there is a better way to do it using a RelativeSource binding.

Another option would be to add a 'LostFocus' command to your Item's ViewModel (E.G. Purchase.LostFocus) and bind to this. You could then have this command call the UpdateOrders method on the parent 'ViewModel' class or have it raise an event that 'ViewModel' listens to.

Something useful that I didn't find out about for a while was the Output window (Debug > Windows > Output). This shows bindings that fail and the path of the binding that is trying to be resolved.

Comment: I'm using Silverlight! That didn't work. The output window is a useful tip. It is now showing: System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'UpdateOrdersCommand' property not found on 'WMS.WCF_WingService.Purchasing' 'WMS.WCF_WingService.Purchasing' (HashCode=53022201). BindingExpression: Path='DataContext.UpdateOrdersCommand' DataItem='System.Windows.Controls.Grid

Comment: Try giving your ItemsControl a name and then using that name for the ElementName in the Command binding. This is a bit hackish but it requires the least amount of change to your current code.

Comment: Still no event firing. It's looking to my View for the Command and not my ViewModel.. Would DataItem or Find Ancestor work? I've tried endless variations

Comment: RelativeSource with AncestorType should work if you are using Silverlight 5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.ancestortype%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: I still can't figure this out. The link you posted is similar but not quite the answer. That InvokeCommandAction doesn't want to fire.

Comment: I finally got the Event to fire:
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}, Path=DataContext.UpdateOrdersCommand}" />

Comment: But now my textboxes have lost TwoWay Binding capability